# Traceback error with Python when using ffmpeg to convert a video

Tags: python, ffmpeg

The simple way my script runs is the user provides a folder location and a filetype and glob.glob() finds the files with the filetype provided and adds them to a list. It then uses a for loop and goes through the list and converts each video. But it doesn't like when I try to run my ffmpeg command. Any help would be awesome. I'm also using Win 7 64 bit with 64 bit ffmpeg and Python 3.3
Here's the error:

```
OS Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1106, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Workspace\PythonConverter\HTMLandPythonConverter\Converter.py", line 77, in <module>
    massConvert(fileNames)
  File "C:\Users\user\Workspace\PythonConverter\HTMLandPythonConverter\Converter.py", line 47, in massConvert
    convertVideotoNewFormat('.mp4', x)
  File "C:\Users\user\Workspace\PythonConverter\HTMLandPythonConverter\Converter.py", line 61, in convertVideotoNewFormat
    myFile = subprocess.Popen(ffmpegString)#, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 820, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
    raise WindowsError(*e.args)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import glob

fileNames = []
fileLocation = {}
filetype = {}
def convertString(location):
    s = list(location)
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] in '\\':
            s[i] = '/'

    if s[len(s)-1] != '/':
        s.append('/')
    location = "".join(s)
    return location

def convertStringBack(stringTo):
    s = list(stringTo)
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] in '/':
            s[i] = '\\'
    stringTo = "".join(s)
    return stringTo

def fileTypeTester():
    FieldType = '*' + input('What\'s the file type we are converting from?')
    typeSplit = list(FieldType)
    if typeSplit[1] != '.':
        typeSplit.insert(1,'.')
    FieldType = "".join(typeSplit)
    if FieldType not in ['*.flv','*.kdb']:
        print('Not a valid file type')
    else:
        return FieldType
    return None

def massConvert(listOfFiles):
    print('Starting Conversion')
    for x in listOfFiles:
        #x = convertStringBack(x)
        print('Converting ' + x + ' to .mp4')
        convertVideotoNewFormat('.mp4', x)
    print('Finished File Conversion')


def convertVideotoNewFormat(newFormat, fileLoc):
    newFilePath = fileLoc[0:len(fileLoc)-4]
    ffmpegString = ["ffmpeg64","-i", fileLoc,"-qscale","0","-ar","22050","-vcodec","libx264",newFilePath,newFormat]
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(newFilePath)
    except OSError:
        print('OS Error')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print('Subprocess Error')
    myFile = subprocess.Popen(ffmpegString)
    print(myFile)

#This will replace old HTML flv object tag with new video tag, but it is yet to be implemented
def replaceHTML():
    pass

fileLocation = input('What is the path of the files you\'d like to convert?')
fileLocation = convertString(fileLocation)
fileType = fileTypeTester()
fileNames = glob.glob(fileLocation + fileType)
massConvert(fileNames)
```

I've looked around and most of the tutorials are in 2.7 the code is 3.3 and I can't find a tutorial to use ffmpeg for 3.3. My ffmpeg is set to 'ffmpeg64' on my PATH.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `ffmpeg64` is on your `PATH`? (And are you sure that the `PATH` in the DOS prompt you're looking at is the same `PATH` that Python is seeing? If you just `SET` it at the prompt, it only affects non-GUI programs that you run from that same prompt.)

Comment: Also, 2.7 `subprocess` code pretty much runs unchanged in 3.3 (as long as you're not trying to pass non-ASCII characters as parameters, which you're not). So, your tutorials should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

```
def convertVideotoNewFormat(newFormat, fileLoc):
    newFilePath = fileLoc[0:len(fileLoc)-4]
    ffmpegString = ["ffmpeg64","-i", fileLoc,"-qscale","0","-ar","22050","-vcodec","libx264",newFilePath,newFormat]
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(newFilePath)
    except OSError:
        print('OS Error')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print('Subprocess Error')
```

This part cannot possibly do anything useful. The `newFilePath` is a path you've made by stripping the last 4 characters off a video file. You can't run the program at that path, because (unless you get very, very unlucky) there is no such problem.

That explains the first `OSError`.

---

For the second error, it's telling you that `ffmpeg64` isn't on your `PATH`. You say that it *is* on your `PATH`, but there is no other way that you could get that error from [that line of code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cd9141a4f999/Lib/subprocess.py#l1099). You can look up what [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does if you want.

There are three common reasons for this:

1. You've used `SET` to modify the `PATH` in a particular cmd.exe session (DOS prompt), but you're running code in a different DOS prompt, or running GUI code, or for some other reason have a different session.
2. You've used the control panel to modify `PATH` for your user, but you're running the Python script as a different user (e.g., as part of a WSGI service).
3. You haven't modified `PATH` at all; you're relying on the fact that you've `cd`'d into the same directory as `ffmpeg64`, and `.` is on the default `PATH` in Windows.

---

As a side note, this:

```
newFilePath = fileLoc[0:len(fileLoc)-4]
```

… is the same as:

```
newFilePath = fileLoc[:-4]
```

… except that it's harder to read, and less robust (it will raise an exception if `fileLoc` is under 4 characters wrong), and slower and easier to get wrong.

But really, if you want to strip off an extension, you don't want *either*. If you have `foobar.mpeg`, do you really want to turn that into `foobar..mp4`? Use the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module to munge paths:

```
newFilePath, ext = os.path.splitext(fileLoc)
```

---

While we're at it, you've got some other problems in your code:

```
myFile = subprocess.Popen(ffmpegString)
print(myFile)
```

`subprocess.Popen` creates a subprocess object, which you are eventually going to have to `wait` on. Printing it out won't do anything particularly useful.

If you want to do the conversions one at a time, waiting for each one to finish before doing the next, use `check_call`, not `Popen` here.

If you want to kick them all off in parallel, `return myFile` here, and then do something like this:

```
children = []
for x in listOfFiles:
    print('Converting ' + x + ' to .mp4')
    children.append(convertVideotoNewFormat('.mp4', x))
for child in children:
    child.wait()
print('Finished File Conversion')
```

Comment: Thanks for helping my nub self out, I'm really new to python and appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with ffmpeg, I didn't command prompt it into the path, I used the advanced system settings  -> environment Variables and added to the PATH with ';C:\ffmpeg\bin' and it's in that file. [Picture 1](http://imgur.com/8jUo1qH) and [Picture 2](http://imgur.com/4BjHKkb)

Comment: First, in your Picture 2, there's no program called `ffmpeg64` there. There's an `ffmpeg`, but that's not the same name.

Comment: Also, how are you testing the Python script? If you already had a command prompt open before editing the advanced system settings, and are using that one to run the script, it will still see the old values; you have to open a new command prompt to run the script in.

Comment: I'm using an eclipse plugin called PyDev to edit and run the code. I changed it to make it easier, and I switched computers.

Comment: I don't know if PyDev will pick up the changes each time you run the script, or if you need to do something to force it to pick them up (quitting and relaunching should certainly work, but it may not be necessary). But if the problem is the filename (`ffmpeg64` vs. `ffmpeg`) rather than the path, this part is a red herring anyway.

Comment: I've ran a sample of the ffmpeg command and it works, but when running the script from idle or eclipse it fails

Comment: I got it to work, it was just an overly complicated command, and thanks for everything!